How to read headers from axios post in django?
I am sending an axios post to my django backend app:
async function sendBookingRequest() {
    // console.log(date,bookedHours,cancha,cellphone)
    try {
        axios.post("https://danilo2588.pythonanywhere.com/book", {
            headers: {'Authorization':"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"},
            params:{
                'requested_date':date,
                'hours':bookedHours,
                'business':cancha,
                'phone':cellphone,
                }
        })
        .then( function(response){
            setConfirmation(response.data)
            setStepper(7)
        })
        .finally(
            setIsLoading(false)
        )
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }; }

In my views I have:
def booking(request):
    auth_key = request.headers.get('Authorization')

    if auth_key:
        generic_user = Token.objects.get(key=auth_key).user

        if request.method == "POST" and generic_user:
            #do whatever needed...

However the views is not reading the headers and throws an error. I could simply remove the Authentication/token line and voila! but the thing is that I want to keep the code as secure as possible.
What is wrong with my code?

I hope this codebase helps you to solve the problem.
async function sendBookingRequest() {
    setIsLoading(true); // Start loading before making the request
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            "https://danilo2588.pythonanywhere.com/book",
            {
                requested_date: date,
                hours: bookedHours,
                business: cancha,
                phone: cellphone,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
                },
            }
        );
        setConfirmation(response.data); // Handle successful response
        setStepper(7);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); // Log or handle the error
    } finally {
        setIsLoading(false); // Stop loading after the request
    }
}

And you can refer this documentation for axios configuration.
https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example
Thanks
